# multiple java agent proxy the same class

Tags: javaagents

If I use a sequence of java agents to to make bytecode enhancement for the same class . Will the input of the latter be the output of the former?  For example, agent  A adds to  two local variables to methods M, the  input of agent B will contain the same two local vairables in method M?

Comment: Depends on the order of the agents - [which is specified here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the transformer for agent B will be called after the the transformation of agent A:

> When there are multiple transformers, transformations are composed by chaining the `transform` calls. That is, the byte array returned by one call to `transform` becomes the input (via the `classfileBuffer` parameter) to the next call.

[(Source)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html)

The order in which the transformers are called is also specified there:

> Transformations are applied in the following order:
>
> - Retransformation incapable transformers
> - Retransformation incapable native transformers
> - Retransformation capable transformers
> - Retransformation capable native transformers
>
> For retransformations, the retransformation incapable transformers are not called, instead the result of the previous transformation is reused. In all other cases, this method is called. **Within each of these groupings, transformers are called in the order registered.** Native transformers are provided by the ClassFileLoadHook event in the Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface).